# "What are you saying" vs "What you are saying"

Tags: sentence-meaning

I don't understand the correct meaning and concept of the following sentences.

> **1.** I can't hear what **are you** saying?
>
> **2.** I can't hear what **you are** saying?

another example;

> **1.** Where **are you** going?
>
> **2.** Where **you are** going?

Answer (score 0):

In your first block, example 2 is normal usage: "I can't hear what you are saying?" while example 1 would only be normal if you inserted a comma: "I can't hear, what are you saying?"  Both have essentially the same meaning, which is largely "Speak up!"

In your second block, it is the other way around: "Where are you going?" is normal usage, and I can't see a simple way to turn "Where you are going?" into anything normal - closest I can see would be "I don't know where you are going?" but that is quite a substantial change.

"Where are you going?" is fairly low-level - I can't see an easy way to explain it better.

Comment: @kauser Ali  As corrected in Mike's answer, your examples 1. are questions. Examples 2 are statements. But you would have to turn your second example 2 into a full sentence: **Where you are going is dangerous.**

Comment: @ronald-sole Thank you very much. You 100% resolved my problem.